# Regular Expression to allow brackets () to be valiadated

Tags: javascript, regex, forms, validation, livecycle

Using Adobe Live cycle, I am creating a form which contains a telephone number field. The telephone number field should only accept numbers, plus symbols and brackets

At the moment I have an expression for validation that accepts pluses and numbers but when I try to add brackets to it, it seems to break it.

```
if (xfa.event.newText.match(/[^0-9+]/))      
{
    xfa.event.change = "";
}
```

Can someone point me into the right direction please. Thanks!!

Comment: If this is for entry by an end user, you should probably allow for spaces and (depending upon which country you're validating for) hyphens too.

Comment: Why has this been voted down? There are no questions like this already, I couldn't find an answer on Google and I need help. Is that not what SO is for?

Answer (score 3):

You want to include the brackets in the character set:

```
if (xfa.event.newText.match(/[^0-9+()]/)
```

But note that this doesn't really validate actual phone numbers. This would accept `((()))` as a valid phone number.

Validating a phone number is a solved problem, please search around.

Comment: I take that back, for some reason when I tried it before it didn't work. This time it works fine. Would it have IE issues do you think? @Second Rikudo

Comment: @sMilbz: Please, show some sample strings that failed with this regex.

Comment: Shouldn't. If it does, Please try to make a testcase where it fails in IE.